# Why pandas DataFrame allows to set column using too large Series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

Is there a reason why pandas raises ValueError exception when setting DataFrame column using a list and doesn't do the same when using Series? Resulting in superfluous Series values being ignored (e.g. 7 in example below).

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1],[2]])
>>> df
   0
0  1
1  2
>>> df[0] = [5,6,7]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3655, in __setitem__
    self._set_item(key, value)
  File "D:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3832, in _set_item
    value = self._sanitize_column(value)
  File "D:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4529, in _sanitize_column
    com.require_length_match(value, self.index)
  File "D:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\common.py", line 557, in require_length_match
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Length of values (3) does not match length of index (2)
>>>
>>> df[0] = pd.Series([5,6,7])
>>> df
   0
0  5
1  6
```

Tested using python 3.10.6 and pandas 1.5.3 on Windows 10.

Comment: can u explain what did u expect and what u want exactly.

Comment: Consistency ░░░░░

Answer (score 1):

You have right the behaviour is different between `list` and `np.array` but it's expected.

If you take a look in the source code in the [frame.py](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/1.5.x/pandas/core/frame.py) module you will see that if the value is a `list` then it checks the length, in `np.array` doesn't check the length and as you observed is the `np.array` is larger, its truncated.

***NOTE:** The details of the `np.array` truncation is [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/3ae2de9311c870074cfb2a7a4cdd5f88e2cab84c/pandas/core/construction.py#L493)*

[image]